# numpy arrays losing precision when passed to a loop, so comparisons aren't working

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, precision

I have a function that is passed an array of coordinates in 1D. These are the ends of sections for which piecewise functions have been defined in a dictionary, and also passed in as input. However, when making comparisons, the array values change precision in the loop, and so the comparison is not working anymore. Here is the code:

```
def parse_mass_data(mass_prop_file, slices, wingline, y_coords):
    data = pd.read_csv(mass_prop_file, delim_whitespace=True,index_col=False, skiprows = 10, skipfooter=(slices+5))
    cogy = []
    mass = []
    y = y_coords.astype(np.float64)
    print(y)
    for i in range(len(data['Name'].values)):
        if data['Name'][i] != 'Totals'and data['Name'][i] != 'Name':
            cogy.append(data['cgY'].values[i])
            mass.append(data['Mass'].values[i])

    cogy = np.array(list(map(float,cogy)))
    mass = np.array(list(map(float,mass)))
    x = np.zeros(len(mass))
    z = np.zeros(len(mass))

    for i in range(len(mass)):
        for j in range(len(y_coords)-1):
            if cogy[i] >= y[j] and cogy[i] < y[j+1]:
                x[i] = wingline['xy'][j][0] * cogy[i] + wingline['xy'][j][1]
                z[i] = wingline['yz'][j][0] * cogy[i] + wingline['yz'][j][1]
            # print(wingline['xy'][j],wingline['yz'][j])
            print(y[j],y[j+1])
        # print(i,x[i],cogy[i],z[i])
```

The output is as follows:

```
[ 0.  6. 10.]
0.0 5.999999999999999
5.999999999999999 9.999999999999998
0.0 5.999999999999999
5.999999999999999 9.999999999999998
0.0 5.999999999999999
5.999999999999999 9.999999999999998
0.0 5.999999999999999
5.999999999999999 9.999999999999998
```

As you can see, the input array, and the values from the loop index don't match, preventing the comparisons from working. How can I make this comparison, or there a better way of implementing this?

I understand that numpy has an interpolate function here, but I already have the equations to fit the values to, and if the input data is not good to begin with, can I use that function?

Comment: They do match, just to numerical precision. That's what happens when you work with floating point numbers.

Comment: See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) on the issues arising from storing decimal float values in binary. **isclose** functions are available for comparisons.

Comment: You have a couple of pandas dataframes, `data` and `wingline`.  What's the dtypes?  If column dtype  is already float, you shouldn't need that `map(float, ...)` stuff.  '>='  kinds of comparisons on floats are not reliable.  If you can work with integers this would be better.

Comment: @jared so the numpy representation of 6. is not an integer?

Comment: @keg504 Not when you explicitly convert it to `np.float64` type, no

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've solved the problem based on the link @user19077881 provided, and posted the answer below. I'm not sure if it meets the standards for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to how computers work, this is a known problem according to the this similar question: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

My solution was to use absolute value comparisons, as suggested in the accepted answer to that question.
Here is the edited code:

```
mass = np.array(list(map(float,mass)))
x = np.zeros(len(mass))
z = np.zeros(len(mass))

for i in range(len(mass)):
    for j in range(len(y_coords)-1):
        if cogy[i] >= 0:
            if abs(cogy[i] - y_coords[j] > 0.0001) and abs(cogy[i] - y_coords[j+1] <= 0.0001):
                x[i] = wingline['xy'][j][0] * cogy[i] + wingline['xy'][j][1]
                z[i] = wingline['yz'][j][0] * cogy[i] + wingline['yz'][j][1]
        else:
            if abs(cogy[i]) - abs(y_coords[j]) >= 0.0001 and abs(cogy[i]) - abs(y_coords[j+1]) < 0.0001:
                x[i] = -wingline['xy'][j][0] * cogy[i] + wingline['xy'][j][1]
                z[i] = -wingline['yz'][j][0] * cogy[i] + wingline['yz'][j][1]
```

Comment: Hi, you understand the problem and suggest a reasonable solution.  I would suggest you take a look at np.allclose/np.isclose which are  builtin functions to address the exact problem the OP is facing.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that function, I'll use that next time!